# What is the main materials of the windshield? And how do they function in bird strike?

Tags: windows, bird-strike

I would like to know what the latest materials used for civil and military aircraft windshields are.
And I wonder if the materials are advantageous in the event of a birdstrike.

Comment: Searching for "airplane windshield material" found me this: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/44412/what-materials-are-used-for-aircraft-windshields

Comment: This question is too vague and subjective to be answered. There are vast differences in the construction, size, thickness, lamination, and angles of windshields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the latest and greatest.

http://www.ppgaerospace.com/getmedia/926cb26f-e047-477d-b604-62d079f494bc/B787_TD_FINAL.pdf.aspx?ext=.pdf

You will notice that instead of multiple glass laminations separated by plastic interlayers of traditional aircraft windshields, the 787's windshields are basically two thick layers of acrylic plastic (plexiglas) as the main structural element, with interlayers to separate them and just a single outer layer is high strength glass.   This would provide superior birdstrike resistance while the glass outer layer maintains a hard outer surface that won't scratch easily.